# I reset my Keystore password

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

I was in the in the process of singing my apk for my release and i forgot keystorepassword so i clicked reset. then I got this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key "app name" key from store "C:\keystore\keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

What is my best way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you forgot your password, there is no way to fix this. If your application is not published to the playstore, you are free to change the sign-in cert to a new one. Otherwise you will not be able to update your app at playstore, you have to unpublish your current app, change the package name and publish a new one with a different key and package. So always try keep a backup of your cert file and password.

Comment: and i looked again, I reset the masterkey not the keystore

Comment: resetting master key will not help, it just resets the password for android studio's password store

Comment: cool, so if i reset the masterkey and not the keystore password im okay?

Comment: If you know the password for the cert file, what is the problem?  You can use java keytool to verify your password is correct. all the best :)

Comment: I forgot my key store password. Is there any hope to get back this password? I am unable to update my application on play store :( .

Comment: No way exists if you are using your own signing cert for generating Signed APK

Comment: No, The solution for this is to create a new upload key file and appeal google to replace that for you. Now next time you can use this newly generated upload key to sign your application and release the app

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to find

> lost password and keyAlias

from the Android Studio itself, Make it to *project then select .gradle -> select the latest version (in mine its 4.6) -> taskHistory.bin*

then search for

> keyAlias , keyPassword , storePassword

cheers :D you got your passowrds and keyAlias ... Happy building release APK

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Thanks for the tip but what about the question mark symbol and the values both being the same in your example? Is that the actual text?

Comment: this answer save my day

Answer (score 1):

Open the project in Android Studio. On the left pane select Project option to display all the files and folders in your project. You'll find the .gradle folder, inside that you'll find the folder with your gradle number, mine was 5.1.1

Inside that folder, you'll find the executionHistory Folder, and inside that executionHistory.bin file. Open that file in Android Studio itself.

Now search(Ctrl+f) in that file for signingConfig.keyPassword and you'll find more than 1 matches. GO THROUGH ALL OF THEM and you'll find your password after one of these matches.

PS - I'm using Android Studio 3.5

[My Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbny1.png)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
On Windows, I found the keystore file path, password, key alias and key password in an earlier log report before I updated Android Studio.

From windows file explorer c:/Users/your pc name/.AndroidStudio2.0 (your android studio version)\system\log\idea.log.1 (or any old log number)

Then I searched for “password” and found this from an earlier date:

-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file= path to your keystore 
-Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password= KEYSTORE PASSWORD
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias= KEY ALIAS
-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password= YOUR_KEY_PASSWORD
```

Comment: i have that file, not sure how to open it to see that. my keystore jks

Comment: Open in Notepad .

Comment: yeah, i did that before but the font wasn't anything legible.